# android studio cant activate AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

Im working with `android studio 1.5.1` and Im trying to extend `AppCompatActivity` Class but for some reason the studio cannot see it. I searched a bit on the Internet and couldn't find a solution which would guide me step by step on to solve it?

(it says on the class `Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'`)

Comment: Could you show your build.gradle file the one under app not the project

Comment: Here's the line you need in build.gradle: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1' (or any other version)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your app includes the AppCompat support library. In your `build.gradle` for the app (not the top-level project), make sure to have:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Then sync Gradle. You might need to adjust the version of the library to whatever you have installed with your SDK.